# Androidアプリで情報を保存して、また後で同じ情報にアクセスする方法？

Tags: android, java

こんにちは！私はJavaの初心者である外国人です。Javaの基本的な知識を勉強したが、なんかどこから始めたらいいか分かりません。
Android Studioでアプリを作りたいけど、Javaの上にそれを習うのは相当難しいことになるんじゃないかなと思っています。

とにかく、名前、メールアドレス、誕生日等を保存する簡単なものを作りたいと思っています。
ただ、Eclipseでそういうものを作っても、プログラムから出ると全ての入力された情報がなくなってしまうんじゃないですか？

だから、長くなってすみませんが、プログラムを起動して、情報を入れたりして、プログラムから出ても、どうやってまたそのプログラムを起動したら全ての入れた情報にアクセスすることが出来ますか？

Comment: Androidアプリですか？
Would you develop Android app with Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio!Javaの方なら分かるけど、android:idとかandroid:viewなどが入ると分からなくなってしまいます（笑）Are you an android developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android アプリでで少量のデータを保存し、アプリが再度起動されたときにそのデータを復元するには  SharedPreferences というクラスを使うのが簡単です。

公式サイトの Getting Started (スタートガイド) だと、

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

で説明されています。英語の資料を読むのが苦手ならば SharedPreferences でググれば沢山サンプルも出てくると思います。

データの量が多い時は、普通のファイルにデータを保存する事もできますし、SQLite データベースを使うこともできますが、
まずは SharedPreferences を使ってみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます！そのサイトがすごく役に立ちそうですね。まだ分からなかったらググります(^_^)
頑張ります！また、ありがとう！

Comment: こちらのサンプルコードも、もし参考になればどうぞ。
http://techbooster.org/android/application/11103/